# Validation in modal form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a simple modal form in which I have to check user entered data. But after validation the form gets closed. It behaves like this because of not empty DialogResult property but I need this value for other purposes (in a parent form)
Any ideas?

A little code to clear things up

```
//This method creates and calls a modal form. 
public static Definition edit(Definition w)
{
    EditForm ed = new EditForm();
    DialogResult dr = ed.ShowDialog();
    if (dr == DialogResult.OK)
    {
       //update some fields of passed object
    }
    //other code
}

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       if (validateForm())
       {
           DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes;
           Close();
       }
}
```

Comment: Will you further explain your problem? I can't your question.

Comment: Some code would help - but it sound like you are abusing the `DiaglogResult`. What are you using it for in the parent form?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it this way:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       if (validateForm())
       {
           DialogResult = DialogResult.Yes;
           Close();
       }
       else
       {
           DialogResult = DialogResult.None;
       }
}
```

I.e. as you said, clear the `DialogResult`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a `FormClosing` event handler and then if the validation fails set `e.Cancel = true`:

```
private void EditForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        e.Cancel = !ValidateInput();
    }
}
```

This will leave you sub form open and let the user correct the mistakes. You can check whether the "OK" or "Cancel"/Window Close button has been clicked by checking the `DialogResult` and only performing the validation if it's `OK`.

Comment: @drv - you don't set it if the validation fails. Not that it really matters as you're not calling `Close()` so the sub form stays open.

Comment: Well, I set the ok_button DialogResult property to 'OK' and it didn't work, even if Close wasn't called. The form gets closed either way. It seems to work better when the property is set to 'OK' only in event handler. But i have to check it to make sure:)

Comment: @drv - odd. Can you add the `EditForm` code (just the OK button click handling) to the question.

Comment: @drv - my mistake. It's the `FormClosing` event you need to handle. I've updated my answer.

Comment: But what about the standard window close button? And one more thing - are the buttons event handlers (Save/Cancel) unnecessary in this solution?

Comment: @drv - see my update - the button event handlers are still needed